# Realm JS : querying a string inside a list of string (Mongo equivalent to elemMatch)

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

Say I have a collection Pastries like this :

```
[
    { 
    name: "chocolate",
    theyLikeIt : [{value:"Paul"}, {value:"Oliver"}, {value:"John"}]
    },
    { 
    name: "banana",
    theyLikeIt : [{value:"Sarah"}, {value:"John"}]
    }
]
```

How could I retrieve all the pastries that John likes ? 
In Mongo it would be something like :

```
find({ theyLikeIt: { $elemMatch: { $eq: JohnId } } })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a "dot-notation" to query on child objects. So you should be able to write something like this:

`realm.objects('Person').filtered('theyLikeIt.value = "John"');`